# jQuery Find() and XML does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to parse an in-memory XML document. This works great in everything but IE (shocker). Some googling revealed that the problem is most likely due to the fact that IE is treating my document as HTML rather than XML MIME Type.

Is there a way to make my jQuery implmentation work or do I have to check the client browser and implement IE specific XML parsing?

Thanks!!

```
function getQAData(xmlData) {
var dataArr = new Array();
$(xmlData).find('item').each(function() {
    dataArr.push({ questionid: $(this).attr("cellID"), answer: $(this).find('answer').text() });
});

return dataArr; // this array is nice and populated in everything but ie
```

XML Sample

```
    <hwroot>
    <data pid="">
        <item cellID="24_951">
            <question>Are you there?</question>
            <answer>No</answer>
        </item>
        <item cellID="24_957">
            <question>A Question?</question>
            <answer>blah blah blah</answer>
        </item>
</data>
</hwroot>
```

**Solution:**

My jQuery .find() solution will not work for reasons described by @treeface below. Here is my solution:

Branch JS code based on navigator :(

```
  if (browserName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    MsXmlParse(xmlData, dataArr);

} else {
    $(xmlData).find('item').each(function() {
        dataArr.push({ questionid: $(this).attr("cellID"), answer: $(this).find('answer').text() });
    });
}
```

Definition of MsXmlParse

```
function MsXmlParse(xmlDocument, qarray) {
var xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmldoc.async = "false";
xmldoc.loadXML(xmlDocument);

var itemElements = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("item");

for (var i = 0; i < itemElements.length; i++) {
    var questionCellID = itemElements[i].getAttributeNode("cellID").nodeValue;
    var answerTxt = itemElements[i].childNodes[1].text;

    qarray.push({ questionid: questionCellID, answer: answerTxt });
}
```

} //end msxmlparse

Comment: Well that *could* be an IE problem, but it's even so likely that you're doing something wrong. Can you post the value of xmlData?

Comment: The same XML works in FF. I will post some anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not having any issues with this as you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/treeface/VuwcH/

My guess is that in IE, you're not parsing your XML data properly in the first place, but it's impossible to tell unless you show us the output of that xmlData variable. As you can see in my example, you need to use something other than the `DOMParser` object in order to parse an XML string properly in IE. You have to do this:

```
xmlData = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlData.async = "false";
xmlData.loadXML(text); //where text is your XML string
```

**Edit**:

OK, so is the problem here that your `xmlData` object is a string of XML? You mentioned in your post that it is "an in-memory XML document", in which case it would, and does, work in IE. As far as I can tell from your responses, xmlData is actually *a string*, and that's where the problems arise. IE is the only major browser that has issues with putting non-compliant HTML inside an HTML node. Since jQuery's XML parser wraps the supplied string in a `div`, it craps out in IE. jQuery recognizes this bug and they have considered it a "won't fix" issue.

Issue here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3143

Reason for not fixing: *Check this link :  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery#jQuery2 The jQuery constructor only supports html, not xml. The string is flushed into a div, that probably why IE blows up. Because the string isn't valid html.*

Specifically this bit:

> When the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, as it is in the above example, the actual creation of the elements is handled by the browser's `innerHTML` mechanism. In most cases, jQuery creates a new `<div>` element and sets the `innerHTML` property of the element to the HTML snippet that was passed in. When the parameter has a single tag, such as `$('<img/>')` or `$('<a></a>')`, jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript `createElement()` function.
>
> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. For example, Internet Explorer prior to version 8 will convert all href properties on links to absolute URLs, and Internet Explorer prior to version 9 will not correctly handle HTML5 elements without the addition of a separate compatibility layer.

So I suspect that they "won't fix" it because otherwise things would get sloppy for all other browsers. I'm not sure of the veracity of this answer (or the quality of the logic behind their decision) but that's the way it is.

So...in short (too late?)...no, there is no easy way to handle this in a single line. Then again, there also shouldn't be anything stopping you from using JSON instead of XML.

Comment: This example would be what I consider "IE specific XML parsing". The compliant browsers do not seem to have an issue with the find(). It would be nice to keep the one line jQuery solution. I fear that is not possible. thanks

Comment: Thanks.. as I suspected. Bummer they won't fix it. I have decided to just branch my code based on browser inspection. If the browser is IE I am just parsing the document using the ActiveXDocument (perhaps I can update with my solution; its nearly done). Not a big deal. More of an nuisance really. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, you can fix this in one line if you use jQuery 1.5, which has a new `parseXML()` method. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's normal `jQuery()` / `$()` function doesn't parse the string you pass to it as XML: it pretends it's HTML, and this will not work in general. However, you could use jQuery 1.5's new [`parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) method:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlData);
```

Comment: Nice one, Tim...I didn't know about this.

Comment: Well, this ought to help the weekly onslaught of "Why my xml doesn't work with jquery?". Nice one.

Comment: @Crescent: I wouldn't bank on it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem with all versions of IE or just IE7? I have encountered difficulties using jQuery to parse XML with IE before and the fix ended up being using a different selector to get the data.

Forget looking for items. Try, for example, finding all items with the "cellID" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

A work-around might be to create [shivs](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/) of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

**It's working fine!!! Try this,**

Chrome/Firefox:

```
xml.children[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML
```

IE8+/Safari:

```
xml.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].textContent
```

IE8:

```
xml.documentElement.childNodes[1].text;
```

Sample code here,

```
var xml = $.parseXML(XMLDOC); 

Var xmlNodeValue = ""; 

if(userAgent.match("msie 8.0")){

xmlNodeValue = xml.children[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML;

}else{ // IE8+

xmlNodeValue = xml.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].textContent; 

}
```