# Jquery XML Parse does not work for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, internet-explorer-9

I have run into a situation and need assistance. I am trying to read xml file's content using jquery ajax method as follows:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "Resources/languageResource.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {
    $(xml).find(lang).each(function(){
        var title=$(this).find('title').text();
        var loginBoxHeader1=$(this).find('loginBoxHeader1').text();
        var loginBoxHeader2=$(this).find('loginBoxHeader2').text();
        var username=$(this).find('username').text();
        var password=$(this).find('password').text();
        var submit=$(this).find('LoginBtn').text();
        var RememberCheckbox=$(this).find('RememberCheckbox').text();

        document.getElementById('titleId').innerText = title;
        document.getElementById('h1Id').innerHTML = title;
        document.getElementById('loginBoxHeader1').innerHTML = loginBoxHeader1;
        document.getElementById('loginBoxHeader2').innerHTML = loginBoxHeader2;
        document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = username;
        document.getElementById('password').innerHTML = password;
        document.getElementById('submit').innerHTML = submit;
        document.getElementById('RememberCheckbox').innerHTML = RememberCheckbox;
    });
}
```

});

This works great in Firefox and Chrome but not working for IE. What is missing?

Internet Explorer version is 9.

Here is the xml file structure:

```
<xml>
<English>
    <title>Welcome to ******* System</title>
    <loginBoxHeader1>Login Panel - </loginBoxHeader1>
    <loginBoxHeader2>Please provide following credentials!</loginBoxHeader2>
    <username>Username:</username>
    <password>Password:</password>
    <LoginBtn>Log in</LoginBtn>
    <RememberCheckbox>Remember my login on this computer</RememberCheckbox>
</English>

<Spanish>
    <title>********************************</title>
    <loginBoxHeader1>Login Panel -</loginBoxHeader1>
    <loginBoxHeader2>Por favor, proporcione las credenciales siguientes!</loginBoxHeader2>
    <username>Nombre de Usuario:</username>
    <password>Contraseña:</password>
    <LoginBtn>iniciar la sesión</LoginBtn>
    <RememberCheckbox>Recordar mi usuario en este equipo</RememberCheckbox>
</Spanish>

</xml>
```

Result on Chrome/Firefox:

[image]

Result on IE:

[image]

Comment: May be you can have a look at http://www.newmediafun.com/2009/07/parsing-xml-with-jquery-in-internet-explorer/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998324/jquery-find-and-xml-does-not-work-in-ie

Comment: Does it fail to work in some particular manner worth mentioning? We have no way to find out by ourselves given that we don't even know what the XML looks like.

Comment: The xml file is being read properly in firefox and chrome but not for IE. I have added xml file content now but i think jquery code needs to be fixed by making it work for IE.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: Try using <?xml version="1.0" ?> at the top of the xml document instead of wrapping the thing in <xml></xml> . Maybe IE does not like xml formatted that way?

Comment: @Kyle it did not work.

Comment: You could replace all your 'document.getElementById('elementID')' calls with jquery selectors '$('elementID').text('text/html to set'). Might not fix your problem but would make your code a little cleaner. Your using JQuery anyways, why not leverage it's selector engine?

Comment: @Jeldrik - if you have a problem after upgrading to jquery 1.9, it's likely due to using a deprecated feature; jquery 1.9 dropped a lot of older stuff. They do provide a jQuery.Migrate library that brings back all those old features, if you need them; you should try that.

Comment: @Spudley - Thanks, in my case it was a changed behavior - see below

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it didn't work for me was that in older versions of jQuery the field responseXML of the XMLHttpRequest was evaluated for XML responses. Newer versions seem to take always the DOMParser to parse the raw response which somtimes throws an exception during the pasing of the response, even when there is a vaild dom tree in the responseXML field of the XMLHttpRequest. The exception is propably thrown due to character encoding issues, however if the responseXML does contain a dom tree you can work around this issue:

```
var xhr;

$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "Resources/languageResource.xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   xhr: function () {
      xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
      return xhr;
   },
   success: onSuccess,
   error: function(status, msg) {
      if (status.status == 200) {
         var xml = xhr.responseXML;
         if (xml && xml.documentElement) {
            onSuccess(xml);
         }
      } else {
          // error handling
      }
   }
 });

 function onSuccess(xml) {
    // parsed xml tree
    // ...
 }
```

Strange is however, that responseXML contains a dom tree, whilest the DOMParser is not able to parse the raw response. This issue seems to be fixed with IE10 - is IE9 using two different xml parsers (resonseXML!=DOMParser)? - strange...

Answer (score 0):

In such a situation, helped me reset all the settings IE `(Internet Options -> Advanced -> Reset)`